# Unable to set JRE_HOME variable

Tags: java, pentaho

I am trying to set the Pentaho Server. For that, I need to set JRE-HOME variables.I dont know how to set it.

**Error**

```
>WARNING: Using java from path
>DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=
>DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=java.exe
>Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
>At least one of these environment variables is needed to run this program
```

How to resolve this error.

Comment: Which operating System are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 64 bit.

Comment: this link may help https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/articles/348/configuring-the-java_home-and-jre_home-environment-variables-on-a-windows-server

Comment: Once you define JAVA_HOME by following the link which @SwaritAgarwal mentioned, error will go.